# Flutter: iterate over map with custom index

Tags: flutter

I have a map like this:

[image]

The index is a date converted to a string for I used different methods to iterate over it and didn't work:

```
events.asMap().forEach((i, value) {
      print('index=$i, value=$value');
});

for (var event in events) {
    print(event);
}

events.forEach((event) {
    print(event);
});
```

Comment: can you please add your map as text please? Or if you want print events from your dart code

Comment: I can't, I don't know how to display it, that's the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and it worked:

```dart
  Map<String, List<String>> events = {
    "Date1": ["item1", "item2", "item3"],
    "Date2": ["item4", "item5", "item6"],
    "Date3": ["item7", "item8", "item9"]
  };

  for (var dayEvents in events.entries){
    for (var i = 0; i < dayEvents.value.length; i++){
      print(dayEvents.value[i]);
    }
  }

//output: 
// item1
// item2
// item3
// item4
// item5
// item6
// item7
// item8
// item9
```

Comment: I cannot modify what I have in the database

Comment: but it's not DateTime, it's saved as String

Comment: add for (var i = 0; i < event.value.length; i++) {
        print(event.value[i]);
      } inside it and I'll accept it

Comment: no sorry, I mean inside of what you had:
for (var dayEvents in events.entries) {
      for (var i = 0; i < dayEvents.value.length; i++) {
        print(dayEvents.value[i]);
      }
    }

Comment: Ok changed it again xD